# Как запустить test suite с разными параметрами? (Pytest)

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pytest

Есть набор ui тестов в одном классе:

```
class TestMainPage(object):
    login = 'login'
    password = 'password'

    def test_open_site(self, browser, url):
        """Opening browser and go to website"""
        browser.go_to_site(url)
        browser.check_open_auth_page()

    
    def test_authorisation(self, browser):
        """Аuthorization on the website"""
        browser.authorisation(login=self.login, password=self.password)

    ...
```

Этот набор тестов нужно прогнать с различными параметрами (url, login, password), как это сделать?

Важно, что бы при каждом новом наборе параметров, выполнялись все тесты поочередно, а не как в случае с параметризацией ф-кции,когда один тест выполняется со всеми аргументами и только после этого переходит к следующему тесту

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,expected", testdata)
def test_timedistance_v0(a, b, expected):
    diff = a - b
    assert diff == expected
```

Comment: Как будто, хорошим решением было бы запустить этот набор тестов с помощью цикла, но надеюсь, что есть более элегантное решение

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент нашел вот такое решение:

```
my_list = [5,2,3]
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=my_list)
def my_params(request):
    return request.param

class Test_suite:
    def test_1(self, my_params):
        assert 1==1
    def test_2(self, my_params):
        assert 1 == 1

    def test_3(self, my_params):
        assert 1 == 1
```

По итогу получим:

```
test.py::Test_suite::test_1[5] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_2[5] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_3[5] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_1[2] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_2[2] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_3[2] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_1[3] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_2[3] PASSED
test.py::Test_suite::test_3[3] PASSED
```

В целом, мне этого достаточно.
Ответ нашел на англоязычной части форума: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059738/run-all-tests-once-per-each-parameter-with-pytest)